# ember router error : Object hash has no method 'getURL'

Tags: ember.js, ember-old-router

i just switched to ember-latest v1.0.pre-160-g7d62790, from v1.0.pre-42 and now my router is throwing the error : TypeError: Object hash has no method 'getURL'  when it is starting up.

the app is auto initializing.  i've dug into the source and the offending line is 11264: router.route(location.getURL());

in this case location is 'hash' which is the default value of Router.location.. i think it's supposed to get set as a HashLocation internally when the router initializes..  hence the getURL() call.

but it's remaining as a string. i suspect this has to do with some kind of initializing being out of whack, but i can figure out why.  anyone else encountered this, or know why it's happening?

Comment: could you post a jsfiddle with the related version of ember ?

Answer (score 3):

solved it myself.  the issue was that i overrode Router.initialize() but did not call super() within it, so the Router didn't complete its initialization.